# What is the best way to run a PHP script at a particular time?

Tags: php, unix, cron

I have a site where auctions end a varying times.  I need to send an automated email to the seller and the buyer after the auction is finished to notify them of the auction ending and the results.  Obviously I can't really wait for someone to load the page to run the script so is there a good way to automate this by checking the current time and comparing that to the time of the auction end and running that script?

The site is on a UNIX server so a cron job is an option, but I'm concerned that running a cron job like that will put quite a load on the server.

Comment: Can I ask what kind of server infrastructure you are running? I presume you are using a timer mechanism in something other than PHP? If you are using something else, I recommend you attach some code to that timer mechanism that also executes a mail-sending script when the timer runs down.

Comment: I'm not aware of any kind of timer I could use except maybe javascript running on the page.  I didn't want to use javascript because I was actually afraid someone manipulate that and cheat on an auction.

Comment: What are you using then to determine who wins the auction? How are you able to determine (with precision) who wins? I would be very careful to use a robust timer mechanism on the back-end (such as in JavaScript in Node.js or Perl or Python... or *anything* really besides PHP). I am starting to get an idea of how your timer is working, being triggered and checking a file/database when a user visits the page? It may now sound difficult and perhaps unnecessary, but as your application grows, you will be *very* glad that you created a core timer in the background that runs all of these mechanisms.

Comment: Yes, but the page is set to refresh every 60 sec.  Do you have any suggestions on how to implement this?  Right now I have an auction end date and time, and when the page loads it checks that against the current date and time.

Comment: Okay, but what happens when a user simply leaves the page? What mechanism is in place to make sure that the auction ends properly and the correct user(s) is notified? With a robust backend like JavaScript /Node (or Perl or whatever if you don't like Node), you can have a *running process* do the calculations and trigger what needs to be triggered, as well as send out notification emails. Also, because it's on the backend, your entire application won't depend entirely on user interaction to function properly. I would say that doing it the way you are now is more dangerous.

Comment: If only because the entire process relies on the user (not to mention the security implications in the process).

Comment: Well, that's my problem... trying to notify the correct user.  I figure if a user isn't interacting with the page then the auction doesn't need to end, but when they do, the time difference is calculated and the user is notified that the auction has ended.  I would rather do this with JavaScript, but I'm not very good with it.

Comment: Well thankfully, JavaScript is really easy to get on board with, especially if you know enough PHP to do what you're already doing. I know it sounds like a monumental task, but you'll thank me later when you run into huge, huge tasking issues when either 1) your application scales or 2) your users begin to complain that they did not receive notification that they lost or won until they visited the page again. Not everybody sits and clicks refresh on eBay, after all.

Comment: Ok, after thinking about it some more, I think a JavaScript timer on the page that checks the auction end date/time and begins a countdown as long as the page is open.  If it finishes while the page is open then is closes the bidding.  On top of that, a cron job that runs every 60 sec. that looks for expired auctions and closes them, as well as sends notification emails.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Word of advice: Never ever trust your clients to do critical work. What I would do in this situation to solve the problem quickly is create a Perl script (since we just pick one we know how to write) that accesses the database of auctions and contains the "heartbeat" of ALL auctions, meaning that it keeps track of the system time and the END of all auctions. Then when an auction ends, it connects to a specially-written local webpage that does all of your emailing and database sorting in PHP. This solution is not the best, but it's a fast fix and stops relying on the client for important stuff.

Answer (score 2):

A cron job runs at most once per minute.

Whatever load it generates on the server really depends on the kind of script you're going to run. Btw, I'm assuming that you're using `cli` to run the script (rather than just doing a `curl http://mysite.com`.

If your script takes longer than one minute (you should monitor this), simply either:

- Increase the interval time between runs or,
- Use a [lock file](http://php.net/flock) to make sure no two instances of your script can run at the same time.

  ```
  if (($fp = fopen('/tmp/mylockfile', "r+")) === false) {
      die("Could not open lock file");
  }
  if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
      die("Could not obtain lock");
  }
  // run your code here

  // release the lock and close file
  fclose($fp);
  ```

OTOH If the script needs to run more than once per minute, you would need a different mechanism entirely.

Comment: 'you should benchmark this', nop! you should make sure your script stops after 59 sec!

Comment: @hek2mgl Wat? You realize how impractical that is, right? Unless you were joking of course.

Comment: No this is required! I've done that.. Having a queue.. Stopping after end of queue or 50 sec. If 50 sec reached -> email to admin. ALERT! . that's good work

Comment: @hek2mgl A simple lock file would suffice, that makes sure another instance cannot run together.

Comment: 'A simple lock file' do it with PHP (not racy).

Comment: @hek2mgl I'm not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: not racy, means not vulnerable against race conditions, btw your answers is *ok* (now). but so is the downvoted answer of @L0j1k. Don't know why downvote

Comment: @hek2mgl Racy means something else altogether, but using advisory locking is an accepted way of preventing multiple runs.

Comment: advisory locking is a good way to deal with that issue as long as you only want a single process to execute things.  If you need to scale out horizontally it won't be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Use Cron. It allows you to run any command at most once per minute: http://clickmojo.com/code/cron-tutorial.html

As far as server load goes, it generally won't be a concern unless you are running a massive number of database calls very often on a very low-end server. I speak in generalities, but the idea is sound.

If you are using something else (besides PHP) to run your auction timer mechanism, I recommend you attach some code to that timer mechanism that also executes a mail-sending script when the timer runs down to zero and determines a winner.

Comment: OP said: *cron job is an option, but I'm concerned that running a cron job like that will put quite a load on the server*. In case you were wondering, it wasn't MY downvote.

Comment: It wasn;t my down vote, but probably because you say "any time you desire". That is not true, at most 1 minute intervals. With an auction this is not handy.

Comment: Right, so execute the option: Use cron. Sorry you didn't understand that.

Comment: That's my concern.  Sending emails could get cumbersome for the server if the site usage grows.  I'm concerned that there could be 100's of emails per each cron job... but if the script is sending 1 email per script (instead of 100 BCC's), would they send simultaneously?

Comment: Even sending hundreds of mails *per minute* will not produce the kind of load you should be worried about. Hundreds of mails *per second* perhaps, but not a few hundred per minute.

Comment: And then it's likely you will run into problems with mail routing (i.e. triggering a spam flag at your ISP) before you run into problems with your server processing the outbound mail.

Comment: No problem. I hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Q: What is the best way to run a PHP script at a particular time, or interval?
A: Use [cron](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html)

Q: Does a cronjob create a big load on the server?
A: Depends off course off your script. But checking if an auction should be closed, close it and send two emails shouldn't be to difficult. Be sure to create some kind of lockfile to make sure that *if* your script runs longer than the interval set, it isn't run twice.

Q: running a script with shorter intervals than 1 minute
A: Can't answer this one for you. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Run the PHP script as a command line script. This will not put a load on the webserver - just a load on the server and you can easily run it via CRON.

If you add `#!/usr/bin/php` to the top of the script and change the execute bit on the file with `chmod +x scriptname.php` you can directly execute the script without passing it through php

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Comment: Well, with `#!/usr/bin/php` actually *does* pass this through PHP, but directly to the interpreter.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to running it via `php scriptname.php` vs `scriptname.php`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you need to do this:

1. Store something in your auction information indicating whether you've sent this e-mail yet or not (could be a boolean or a date for when it was sent which might be null).  Although I have to assume you need to do something besides send this e-mail?  Like mark the auction as closed so no more bidding can take place?
2. A bit of code that finds auctions which need this e-mail sent: e.g. they've ended and have not yet been reminded.
3. Something to repeatedly execute the bit of code in 2.  You could use cron.  Alternatively you can write a pretty simple daemon for unix that runs constantly in a loop of (wait at least a few ms or more; do some stuff).  The latter is a lot more work but in my opinion scales much better.  See http://pear.php.net/package/System_Daemon for some useful tools if you're interested in this approach.

One thing to consider is how much you want to be careful about accidentally double-sending this e-mail.  If you're only running this code in a single thread it's pretty easy but if you ever want to build out to the point where you have several different distributed machines that create and send these e-mails you have to be a bit more careful.  If you're running it out of cron can you guarantee one run of it will always be finished before another one starts?